# Missing labels in barchart

Tags: tikz-pgf, bar-chart

I'm trying to draw a barchart but the text that I underlined and colored as green doesn't seem to display.

This is how it appears.

[image]

The following is the code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\newcommand{\ImageWidth}{11cm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,positioning, arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\scalebox{0.72}{ % Adjust the scale factor as needed
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ 
height=19.58cm,
width=15.44cm,
xbar, xmin=-1000, xmax=25000,
xlabel={Time elapsed since the first kernel driver (module) was unloaded (in seconds)},
symbolic y coords={
    \underline{\textcolor{red}{mdd.sys}},
    \underline{\textcolor{red}{Beep.SYS$^4$}},
    \underline{\textcolor{red}{Beep.SYS$^3$}},
    \underline{\textcolor{red}{Beep.SYS$^2$}},
    \underline{\textcolor{red}{Beep.SYS$^1$}},
    \underline{\textcolor{red}{imapi.sys}},
    \underline{\textcolor{red}{processr.sys}},
    \underline{\textcolor{red}{Cdaudio.SYS}},
    \underline{\textcolor{red}{Sfloppy.SYS}},
    \underline{\textcolor{green}{kmixer.sys}},
    \underline{\textcolor{green}{drmkaud.sys}},
    \underline{\textcolor{green}{DMusic.sys}},
    \underline{\textcolor{green}{aec.sys}},
    \underline{\textcolor{green}{swmidi.sys}},
    \underline{\textcolor{green}{splitter.sys}},
    \underline{\textcolor{green}{Serial.SYS}},
    \underline{\textcolor{green}{Parport.SYS}},
    \underline{\textcolor{green}{imapi.sys}},
    \underline{\textcolor{green}{redbook.sys}},
    \underline{\textcolor{green}{intelppm.sys}},
    \underline{\textcolor{green}{Cdaudio.SYS}},
    \underline{\textcolor{green}{Sfloppy.SYS}},
    \underline{\textcolor{green}{Flpydisk.SYS}},
    \underline{\textcolor{green}{Fdc.SYS}}
    },
ytick=data,
nodes near coords, 
nodes near coords align={horizontal},
scaled x ticks=false,
]
\addplot [fill=red!30,draw=red, postaction={pattern=north east lines}] coordinates {
    (13450,\underline{\textcolor{red}{mdd.sys}})
    (8168,\underline{\textcolor{red}{Beep.SYS$^4$}})
    (8168,\underline{\textcolor{red}{Beep.SYS$^3$}})
    (8168,\underline{\textcolor{red}{Beep.SYS$^2$}})
    (8167,\underline{\textcolor{red}{Beep.SYS$^1$}})
    (0,\underline{\textcolor{red}{imapi.sys}})
    (0,\underline{\textcolor{red}{processr.sys}})
    (0,\underline{\textcolor{red}{Cdaudio.SYS}})
    (0,\underline{\textcolor{red}{Sfloppy.SYS}})
    };
\addplot [fill=green!30,draw=green, postaction={pattern=north east lines}] coordinates {
    (20324,\underline{\textcolor{green}{kmixer.sys}})
    (20145,\underline{\textcolor{green}{drmkaud.sys}})
    (20142,\underline{\textcolor{green}{DMusic.sys}})
    (20141,\underline{\textcolor{green}{aec.sys}})
    (20139,\underline{\textcolor{green}{swmidi.sys}})
    (20132,\underline{\textcolor{green}{splitter.sys}})
    (19881,\underline{\textcolor{green}{Serial.SYS}})
    (19880,\underline{\textcolor{green}{Parport.SYS}})
    (9,\underline{\textcolor{green}{imapi.sys}})
    (9,\underline{\textcolor{green}{redbook.sys}})
    (8,\underline{\textcolor{green}{intelppm.sys}})
    (1,\underline{\textcolor{green}{Cdaudio.SYS}})
    (0,\underline{\textcolor{green}{Sfloppy.SYS}})
    (0,\underline{\textcolor{green}{Flpydisk.SYS}})
    (0,\underline{\textcolor{green}{Fdc.SYS}})
    };
\legend{Infected memory image, Baseline memory image}  
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
} % End of \scalebox
\caption{Timeline depicting unloaded kernel drivers (modules) from both memory images.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

It would be great if someone could help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `\underline` and `textcolor` with symbolic `y coords list` seems like an explosive mix !

Comment: @JeT Do you recommend a better way for me to put it since I am not too experienced with LaTeX and this is the first time I am using the tikz-pgf package?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: @hpekristiansen Thank you for informing me, I have corrected it.

Comment: From my analysis https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/713547/245790 I suggest to think about a different visual representation of your data. E.g. you don't need (horizontal) bars at all, you don't need two colors (a separation line would tell the same) etc. E.g. you could use a simple table, where the bars are just rules of a certain width and length. Also a scatter plot will do. Etc.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the ytick line is part of the story, though really strange things happen with your barplot ... :

```
...
    \underline{\textcolor{green}{Sfloppy.SYS}},
    \underline{\textcolor{green}{Flpydisk.SYS}},
    \underline{\textcolor{green}{Fdc.SYS}}
    },
%ytick=data,            % <<<<<<<<
nodes near coords, 
nodes near coords align={horizontal},
scaled x ticks=false,
]
...
```

[image: result]

For reference see this boiled-down version, where I tried to remove all potential trouble-makers ... it's still strange. So probably your (symbolic) coordinates do not work this way?

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

%\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,positioning, arrows.meta}
%\usetikzlibrary{patterns}


\begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[ 
%       height=19.58cm,
%       width=15.44cm,
        xbar, 
%       xmin=-1000, xmax=25000,
%       xlabel={Time elapsed since the first kernel driver (module) was unloaded (in seconds)},
        symbolic y coords={
            mddsys,
            kmixersys,
            },
%       ytick=data,
        nodes near coords, 
        nodes near coords align={horizontal},
%       scaled x ticks=false,
    ]
    
    \addplot [fill=red!30,draw=red, 
    %postaction={pattern=north east lines}
    ] coordinates {
        (13450,mddsys)
        };
        
    \addplot [fill=green!30,draw=green, %postaction={pattern=north east lines}
    ] coordinates {
        (20324,kmixersys)
        };
        
    \legend{Infected memory image, Baseline memory image}  
    \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: reduced]